# Type annotation style (to space or not to space)

Tags: python, pep

Having the following function:

```
def foo(x=1):
    print(x)
```

It is clearly stated in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that no spaces should be used around the `=` sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

If we want to type-annotate the `x` parameter. How should we do it?

```
def foo(x:int=1):
def foo(x: int=1):
def foo(x: int = 1):
```

Is there a preferred way? Or even better, is it specified in some PEP? Did not find it in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: Actually they've used spaces in that PEP https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#instantiating-generic-classes-and-type-erasure

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#syntax

Comment: @vishes_shell You are right, thanks. I just searched for the keyword "space" in that PEP and did not find anything (i.e.: no actual rule apart from the examples).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The examples in PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) all use

```
def foo(x: int = 1):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It just seemed to be a bit weird to have all those spaces when in PEP 8 they are discouraged. Also, it seems there is no explicit rule/recommendation in PEP 484 about that (only the code examples).